# Superfish Internet Explorer hover issue

Tags: 7, navigation

I have an embedded youtube video on the home page (content in "#main"). I have a superfish menu (content in "#menu") which works perfectly in Chrome, FF and Opera and not in Safari and IE (not surprised by IE).

Here is my minified page.tpl.php structure:

```
<div id="page">
   <div id="header"></div> 
   <div id="menu">
     menu here
   </div>
   <div id="main">
     video here
   </div> 
   <div id="footer">
     footer
   </div>
</div>
```

I have tried the following:

```
#menu { 
   position:relative; 
   z-index:999; 
}

#main { 
   position:relative; 
   z-index:0; 
}
```

Is there any thing else I can try?

Thanks in advance.

[EDIT]

The menu goes behind the youtube clip on Safari and IE

Comment: What's the issue?

Comment: @Clive sorry, forgot to add what went wrong. I have edited my question

Comment: Ah, you probably need to add `<param name="wmode" value="transparent">` to your object/embed tag

Comment: @Clive I am using the iframe embed. Should I rather use the object embed instead?

Comment: Is it added through a WYSIWYG? If so, just edit the source and add that parameter to the embed code, it should work fine

Comment: @Clive I'm building the iframe in parts so that the client only needs to enter the code

FRONT:
$iframe_front = <iframe width="600" height="355" src="http://www.youtube.com/embed/
IFRAME;

BACK:
$iframe_back = <<<IFRAME
" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>
IFRAME;
?>

then

$iframe_front . $code . $iframe_back

Comment: to be exact the code is as follows:

<?php print $iframe_front.$fields['field_video_id']->content)."?rel=0".$iframe_back; ?>

Comment: Try tacking on `&wmode=transparent` as a parameter to the video URL